# Spring Boot 2 Internationalization across pages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization, locale, spring-internationalization

I'm trying to implement internationalization (English, French) in my Spring Boot application. I've succeeded in being able to read the locale from the URL and have the texts in the page appear in the intended language. For example, if I type `?lang=fr` then all texts appear in French.

However, my application consists of several pages which I navigate around using the `<a href=...>` tag. Strangely, when I click on a link to go to another page, the language sometimes remains the same, but sometimes changes back to the default English language. What's stranger is that this behavior is not consistent; sometimes it takes 3 clicks for the language to revert to English, and sometimes with just 2 clicks, and the behavior differs from browser to browser too (I use Chrome and Firefox).

My understanding is that the locale is stored as a session cookie, intercepted by the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` bean (which is added in the `InterceptorRegistry`) and resolved by the `LocaleResolver` bean. If this is true, then I don't understand why the locale would (sometimes) change from page to page.

Could the problem be in that I'm using the `<a href=...>` tag for navigating around the pages? Would using a button and jQuery be a better option?

Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Here's my Locale configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return slr;
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
}
```

Comment: Which `LocaleResolver` do you use? Show your configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just included my configuration.

Comment: You're using https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/SessionLocaleResolver.html, so the locale is stored in the HttpSession, not in a cookie. The locale goes back to English because the session has ended (due to its inherent timeout).

Comment: @JBNizet does that mean I should set the session's timeout to a number big enough to allow the locale to persist across the different pages? Or would it be better to use a ``CookieLocaleResolver`` instead?

Comment: If the application is stateless and doesn't need a session, you should definitely use a cookie. If it uses a session already, and the session is so short-lived that you frequently lose your locale (and I mean, not after waiting more than half an hour before changing page), then it's up to you to decide if you prefer using a separate cookie, or to bind the locale to the session.

Comment: @JBNizet The application is not stateless and definitely needs a session. The session shouldn't die out everytime I click on a link, though, should it?

Comment: No. It should time out after a period of inactivity (i.e. of no request sent for this session).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190258/discussion-between-eh-khiari-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: @JBNizet Right. The session isn't dying when I switch pages, but the locale keeps defaulting to '1', even though the values I have are 'en' and 'fr'. I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: I don't know either. Maybe you have some forms or links sending a parameter named "lang" with the value 1? Add a debugger breakpoint inside the interceptor.

Comment: I'll do some more digging. If I come across something noteworthy I'll let you know.